# Ошибка при выполнении программы на С

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Здравствуйте, уже задавала вопрос на эту тематику, определилась на вводе данных переменной Х с клавиатуры, но программа опять же пишет что переменная Ч используется но не инициализирована.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double rezult,c,alterbol,x;
 printf("Vvedite znavhenie X:\n");
 x= scanf("%f");
 puts(" Rabota 1 ");
 puts("============================================");
       alterbol=3*pow(x,2)+15*pow(x,3)+25*pow(x,8);
       c=fabs(pow(x,10))+log(199);
      rezult=alterbol/c;
  printf("\a\n Answer:  rezult=%lf, Press any key...", rezult);
  getch( );
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

```
The variable 'x' is being used without being initialized.
```

Comment: Ошибка на самом-то деле здесь

    x= scanf("%f");  // так просто должно упасть

а Вы хотели ввести `x` и это надо делать вот так

    scanf("%f", &x);


Но, поскольку scanf() возвращает целое число (количество успешно введенных элементов формата) и оно присваивается переменной `x`, то я не понимаю откуда берется Ваша диагностика.

Впрочем, судя по <conio.h> это продукт M$...

Comment: @avp это скорее продукт Borland... А номер строки хотелось бы видеть, поскольку какое-никакое, но значение x получает

Comment: @alexlz: неправильный формат в `scanf` — это UB, и имеет право крешнуть программу с затиранием стека.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
      double rezult, c, alterbol, x;

      printf ("Vvedite znavhenie X:\n");
      scanf ("%lF", &x);

      puts (" Rabota 1 ");
      puts ("============================================");

      alterbol = 3 * pow(x, 2) + 15 * pow(x, 3) + 25 * pow(x, 8);
      c = fabs(pow(x, 10)) + log(199);
      rezult = alterbol / c;

      printf ("\a\n Answer:  rezult=%lF, Press any key...", rezult);

      getch ( );
}
```

Comment: @Ковальский, конечно, это учебная программа, но проверить успешность ввода `x` все равно не помешает.

Comment: @avp, извиняюсь, я не понял что вы хотите мне сказать, разъясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Поскольку `scanf()` возвращает число **успешно** прочитанных переменных, то надо написать что-то вроде

     int rc;
     if ((rc = scanf("%lf", &x)) != 1) {
       if (rc == EOF)
         puts ("No data (EOF)");
       else
         puts("Invalid x value");
       exit(1);
     }

или так

    while (printf("Enter X: "), fflush(stdout), (rc = scanf("%lf", &x)) != 1)
      if (rc == EOF) {
        puts ("No data (EOF)");
        exit(1);
      } else {
        char buf[1024];
        puts("Invalid x value, repeate, please");
        scanf("%s", buf);
      }

Comment: @avp, Благодарю за раскрытый ответ! Мне кажется это будет лишнее, так как человек только учиться, зачем ему много лишнего кода? Хотя проверка не помешает.

Comment: Вот и пусть сразу учится, как делать правильно. По крайней мере теперь наверное запомнит, что ввод пользователя неплохо бы проверять (потом будет меньше проблем).

Кстати, вместо 

     scanf("%s", buf);

безусловно, правильней написать

     fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

(еще правильней вызвать функцию (макрос) skipline(), надежно читающую все до конца строки, но это оставим для самостоятельных упражнений)

IMHO понятно, почему.